# How do I place a button in a UIImage for determining different selections?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I have a UIView with a UIScrollView.  I then added a gesture recognizer programmatically to the scrollView for left or right swipe.

I created 3 UIImageViews with a different UIImage each, say 1, 2 & 3.

Ive gotten it so each swipe moves the new UIImageView into the center of the view.  But now I need to distinguish between the image tapped.  The actual tap will kick off a server request and get the data but I must determine the UIImageView tapped because each UIImage is different and will present the user with the server response plus the tapped image.

Each UIImageView actually has a tag set; 1, 2 & 3. My question is, how do I add a UIButton/IBAction to it?  I was thinking of adding a UIButton as "child" of each UIImageView but Im not sure it can be done and I dont know if its the best way to achieve what I want, which is to be able to distinguish which UIImageView was selected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a button with a background image instead of the image with a button-like reactivity.

```
fourthButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fourthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
    [fourthButton setTitle:@"SomeCardButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fourthButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyCard-Value.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fourthButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
```